# How to allow umlauts in AWS Cognito user emails?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Trying to add an user via `aws-sdk` in AWS Cognito usually works just fine. But when you want to create a user with a email that contains umlauts (e.g. here `testö@umlaut.com`) it throws an error.

**Example Code**

```
import { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from "aws-sdk"

const cognito = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ maxRetries: 10, retryDelayOptions: { base: 1000 } })

const userPoolId = /* some id */;
const email = "testö@umlaut.com";

let params: AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AdminCreateUserRequest = {
    UserPoolId: userPoolId,
    Username: email,
    DesiredDeliveryMediums: ["EMAIL"],
    TemporaryPassword: "aAbB1234_!",
    ForceAliasCreation: false,
    // other properties ..
    UserAttributes: [
      {
        Name: "email",
        Value: email,
      },
      {
        Name: "email_verified",
        Value: "true",
      },
      // other user attributes ..
    ],
  }
  
const result = await cognito.adminCreateUser(params).promise();
```

**Error**

```sh
(node:7126) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: InvalidParameterException: Invalid email address format.
    at Request.extractError (<project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (<project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (<project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (<project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:14)
    at Request.transition (<project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (<project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at <project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (<project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (<project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:690:12)
    at Request.callListeners (<project_root>/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Without the umlaut (e.g. `test@umlaut.com` it works as expected).

**Question**

Why AWS Cognito doesn't allow umlauts in emails and how to allow them?

Comment: If o-umlaut is valid for local part in `local-part@domain` then report a bug to Cognito (or AWS SDK).

Comment: @jarmod I think AWS doesnt allow special characters in email address. I tried with `lüder@example.com` I got the same error `Invalid email address format. (Service: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: 2e407e0f-735c-493d-bb6f-2b07436ce9e9; Proxy: null)`

Comment: Under the covers cognito has to use AWS SES and it doesn't support the newer RFC's that allow non-ascii characters for email.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/APIReference/API_Destination.html.  As @jarmod indicates, I'd open a ticket with AWS.

Comment: @stdunbar that might be the case. But documentation doesnt says anything about it. [AdminCreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminCreateUser.html)

Comment: it's also not working if the umlaut is in the domain part: `test@testö.com`

Comment: @ysfaran - the domain part can be handled with SES.  `testö.com` would become `xn--test-8qa.com` when using [Punycode](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3492.html).  See https://github.com/bestiejs/punycode.js for the current supported way of generating this with Javascript.  It sucks that this isn't supported out of the box.